# Firestore auth rule to test reference value in list

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a Firestore auth rule that checks the current user against a list of team members in a team document. The members are stored as document references so I've been trying things like this:

```
match /teams/{document=**} {
    allow read: if path("/users/" + request.auth.uid) in resource.data.members;
}
```

But when I try and access the team document I get told there is an Auth failure.

Each team member has their own document in `/users` using their UID as a key. So a user might be `/users/12345678` and the teams document might have:

```
/teams/team1 {
              members: [/users/12345678, ....]
             }
```

Where the members are Reference types.

So far I've not been able to figure this out as Firestore does not seem to have the concept of a document reference type in it's auth rules.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security rules do have a concept of a reference, and it's represented as a [Path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path) type object.  When a document reference is read by security rules, you have to treat it like a Path.  And that Path will be fully qualified like this:

```
/databases/$(database)/documents/collection/documentId
```

Where $(database) comes from your usual top-level database wildcard match.

So, your rule might be implemented like this:

```
match /teams/{document=**} {
    allow read: if /databases/$(database)/documents/collection/users/$(request.auth.uid) in resource.data.members;
}
```

Note that in security rules, you can build a path simply by starting with a `/`, and use $(foo) for interpolating variables as path components.